# Bash Diff ignore change on one line

Tags: bash, diff

I have two files, file1.txt and file2.txt, and i want to ignore the difference on the time value (time1 and time2).
I tried to do `diff -I "*TimeComparaison*" files1.txt files2.txt` , but it doesn't work. Do you have any other solution ?

file1.txt :

```
latitude {
  value: "150"
}
longitude {
  value: "-120"
}
time1 {
  value: "3580"
}
speed {
  value: "45"
}
time2 {
  value: "50589246"
}
```

And file2.txt :

```
latitude {
  value: "150"
}
longitude {
  value: "-120"
}
time1 {
  TimeComparaison
}
speed {
  value: "45"
}
time2 {
  TimeComparaison
}
```

Comment: `-I` ignores only *pairs* of lines if both lines match. The line from the first file and the line from the second file must both mach. In your case the regex `*TimeComparaison*` didn't match any line since `diff`expects regular expressions and not globs. You have to write `.*` instead of `*` (or leave out the (`.`)`*` all together). However, this won't work as `file1.txt` does not contain `TimeComparaison`. I'm afraid you have to filter the inputs/outputs of `diff` using another command.

Comment: There is no such thing as "bash diff". diff is not part of bash, and can be run (and behaves identically) without bash even installed.

Comment: What is the significance of the file format? It looks like invalid json. If you could work with valid json, it would be very easy to compare just what you wanted

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. The file is an extract from a json file.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sed with process substitution to filter out things that you want diff to ignore. This can be useful for zeroing out timestamps and other noise.

```sh
diff <(sed -f 'normalize.sed' file1.txt) <(sed -f 'normalize.sed' file2.txt)
```

The normalize.sed script deletes time1 {} and time2 {} blocks:

```
/^time[12] {/, /^}/ d
```